# CMake projects with submodules that have redudant dependencies

Tags: cmake, git-submodules

I have the following project structure:

```
root-project/
|-> CMakeLists.txt
|-> src/
    |-> foo.cpp
|-> include/
    |-> foo.hpp
|-> test/
    |-> test_foo.cpp
    |-> googletest/
        |-> CMakeLists.txt
        |-> ...
|-> libs/
    |-> my-lib/
        |-> CMakeLists.txt
        |-> src/
            |-> bar.cpp
        |-> include/
            |-> bar.hpp
        |-> test/
            |-> test_bar.cpp
            |-> googletest/
                |-> CMakeLists.txt
                |-> ...
```

The `root-project` builds an executable called `foo` which depends on the library `my-lib`.  Both the `root-project` and `my-lib` use `googletest` for testing which is included as a `git-submodule`.

I have accepted the fact that I will have redundant `googletest` directories by using `git-submodule`.  However, the issue is that simply using `add_subdirectory` to connect the entire project will end up with multple `gtest` targets.

**My question**: is there a way for `root-project` to build `my-lib` and only see the target `my-lib` and not the testing target `googletest`?  (I.e., can the redundant `googletest` be "hidden" during the build?)

**My second question**: given my rookie CMake status, did I organize these projects in a flawed way?  Is there a more prefered way to organize the projects that avoids this issue?  Some constructive CMake advice is welcomed!

Comment: Are you aware of add_subproject?

Comment: Nope. But I'm thinking I should become familiar with it.

Comment: Though it doesn't seem to exist: https://cmake.org/?s=add_subproject

Comment: Oh sorry, its called external project: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best practice in this case, but what I ended up doing in my project, was write a cmake module `gtest.cmake` for adding gtest to my project. In that module I check if it was already added, and if it was, I just reused the generated `${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}` variable:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(myProject CXX)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/scripts/cmake")

include(gtest)

# myTarget definition

include_directories(${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(myTarget gtest gtest_main)
```

cmake/gtest.cmake:

```
if(gtest_SOURCE_DIR)
    message(STATUS "gtest variables already defined. Skipping.")
else()
    add_subdirectory("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/gtest")
endif()
```

EDIT:
What I do for test targets usually is exclude them from a regular build, using the `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` property of `add_executable`. You can also use that flag for `add_subdirectory` so that way you can have gtest included only if you want to run the tests. For example, you could write something like this in your CMakeLists.txt:

```
# set ${TESTS_SOURCE_FILES} with the source files of your tests

include_directories(${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR})
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_tests EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL ${TESTS_SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_tests gtest gtest_main)
```

And have your `cmake/gtest.cmake` written like this:

```
if(gtest_SOURCE_DIR)
    message(STATUS "gtest variables already defined. Skipping.")
else()
    add_subdirectory("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/gtest" EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
endif()
```

Then, only if you `make` the test target explicitly, by running `make myProject_tests` it will build only what it needs to make the test target.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This will still compile all tests from any subproject though, right?  Just use a common `googletest`?

Comment: @nick That's right. All subprojects will use the first googletest that was loaded.

Comment: Is there a way to exclude tests from sub projects?  When you create a sub project, can you detect if it is being used as part of a larger project?

Comment: @nick I added a section to answer how to exclude tests

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  This seems like exactly what I need.  One last question and then I think this is solved.  Can you say more about what `gtest.cmake` is doing?    Should `gtest_SOURCE_DIR` get set in the `else` statement?

Comment: After some pondering and some googling, I'm wondering if you think this would work... Could I simply do a `IF(TARGET gtest)` to see if `googletest` has already been built instead of adding the `gtest.cmake` file?  Or is the `gtest.cmake` file doing more than I'm thinking?

Comment: I started experimented and answered my own questions. I just conditioned on the existence of target `gtest`. I marked this as solved. Thank you so much for the help!!